# Create a custom heading in scrreprt (normal fontsize, boldface)

Tags: macros, sectioning, lists, koma-script

I finally managed to make an account here, but I have asked 2 questions before without making an account :)
Ok my next question is the following: I am using the class `scrreprt` and the usual commands provided to create headings like `\chapter` etc.
But now I would like to include custom headings within the text, actually very simple, but in form of a macro or predefined command because I will use it a lot. (Maybe I will need more complicated ones later on as well)
So I want it to look like the following:

```
text...then some space


heading in boldface

some space...then text...
even more text...
```

Sorry if this question is trivial, but I am still very new to TeX. Also in the same context, I'd like to customize the looks of enumerate and itemize. I need to ask: Should I create a new command to make it look the way I like, or is it better to change the existing one? If the latter one is correct where should I look? For example I'd like to know how to change indentation, spaces before and after the environment etc.

Comment: If you're using the `scrreprt` class, the [tag:context] tag is inappropriate, so I removed it. Besides that, your question is very broad in its current form -- you should ask separate questions about customizing a) sectioning headings and b) lists. Even better, you could check the top-voted existing questions for [tag:sectioning] and [tag:lists].

Comment: Have you tried the `\minisec` sectioning command provided by the KOMA classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general your decision to create a new macro that logically marks up a certain part of your manuscript is totally reasonable. Allthough i'd like to draw your attention to the `\paragraph` macro, which is provided by many LaTeX classes. It does exactly what you are asking for (:normal fontsize and boldface). If the class you are using does not have it or you want to create another one - though it is existing, you can, by using the internal `\@startsection`. The syntax is:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\TomMsec}{\@startsection{TomMsec}{4}{\z@}%
                     {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                     {-1em}%
                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

Regarding the list-customization you can do

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto{\itemize}{\vspace{.5em}}    %Adds 0.5em vertical space before the environment
\appto{\enditemize}{\vspace{1em}}  %Adds 1em vertical space after the environment
```

for the `itemize` environment. (It is analouge for the `enumerate` environment.) And for indentation of the list items you can patch `\@item`:

```
\makeatletter
\let\saved@@item\@item
\renewcommand{\@item}[1][]{\setlength{\itemindent}{3em}\saved@@item[#1]}
\makeatother
```