# How to achieve custom paragraph (or in general section) numbering and allow references?

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, numbering, cleveref, sections-paragraphs

I used the command `getcurrentref` from [**this question/answer**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34702/get-reference-to-current-section/34706#34706) to achieve a custom numbering when `\paragraph` is used.

I wrapped it into the macro:

```
\newcommand\mybook[1]{\paragraph{B \getcurrentref{subsection}-\getcurrentref{paragraph}: #1}\hfill\par\vspace{0.2\baselineskip}}%
```

And it allows my to get a structure like this:

[image]

It doesn't seem the best solution, but it works.

Basically I'm facing the problem, that the numbering of **subsubsections** should be ignored and the numbering of the paragraph should only contain the current **subsection** and the subsequent paragraph numbers.

However I'd like to reference my custom paragraph with the custom numbering, which does not work, as you see in B 1-2.

**How can I make `\ref` or even better  `\cref` to adapt my custom numbering?**

I thought it should work with customizing the paragraph command directly like [**here**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138859/create-a-custom-heading-in-scrreprt-normal-fontsize-boldface), but I can't get it work.

Any ideas?

I'd need a solution for KOMA-script classes. I need to keep the subsubsections as I need them in other parts of my document.

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% get currentref command
\newcommand\getcurrentref[1]{%
 \ifnumequal{\value{#1}}{0}
  {??}
  {\the\value{#1}}%
} 

% remove label from paragraph, even if numbered
\renewcommand*{\paragraphformat}{}

% custom paragraph heading 
\newcommand\mybook[1]{\paragraph{B \getcurrentref{subsection}-\getcurrentref{paragraph}: #1}\hfill\par\vspace{0.2\baselineskip}}%

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % how many sectioning levels to assign numbers to
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}    % how many sectioning levels to show in ToC  

\begin{document}

\chapter{Books (chapter)}
\section{Fiction (section)}
\subsection{Dystopy (subsection)}

\subsubsection*{George Orwell (subsubsection 1.1.1.1)}

\mybook{Animal Farm (paragraph)}\label{AnimalFarm}

Animal Farm is an allegorical and dystopian novella by George Orwell, first [...]

\mybook{1984 (paragraph)}

Nineteen Eighty-Four, often published as 1984, is a dystopian novel [...]
I'd like to reference Animal Farm (\ref{AnimalFarm}) as B 1-1 [...]

\subsubsection*{Aldous Huxley (subsubsection  1.1.1.2)}

\mybook{Brave New World (paragraph)}

Brave New World is a novel written in 1931 by [...]

\subsection{Historic Novel (subsection)}

\subsubsection*{Ken Follet}

\mybook{The Pillars of the Earth (paragraph)}

\section{Non-Fiction}
\subsection{Cooking}
\subsubsection*{Baking}
\mybook{Baking without flour}
\subsubsection*{Cooking}
\mybook{Cooking without water}

\end{document}
```

Comment: At the moment I don't understand what  you really want to achieve. What should be the output of your references? Is the `0` in `1.1.1.0.1 the issue? This is totally clear, since the `subsubsection` counter is zero at the moment of using it

Comment: You want the books to be numbered, dont you? The book-book counters shall be reset for each increase of book-counter? You then need some kind of personal label, to refer to the custom booky stuff?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I dont want `1.1.1.0.1` to be displayed, I want `B 1-1` to be displayed.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz For the current paragraph I just want to consider the current section and the current paragraph to be considered. The subsection number should be skipped. And with every new section the paragraph numbering should be reset.

Comment: Please try the suggestions first and tell us what should be changed. In my suggestions, booknumber is independent from section numbering. But this can be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not redefining the `\theparagraph`, this will set the reference the easiest way:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% get currentref command
\newcommand\getcurrentref[1]{%
 \ifnumequal{\value{#1}}{0}
  {??}
  {\the\value{#1}}%
} 

% remove label from paragraph, even if numbered
\renewcommand*{\paragraphformat}{}

% custom paragraph heading 
\newcommand\mybook[1]{\paragraph{B \getcurrentref{subsection}-\getcurrentref{paragraph}: #1}\hfill\par\vspace{0.2\baselineskip}}%

\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{B \arabic{subsection}-\arabic{paragraph}}


\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{paragraph}{paragraph}{paragraphs}
\Crefname{paragraph}{Paragraph}{Paragraphs}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % how many sectioning levels to assign numbers to
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}    % how many sectioning levels to show in ToC  




\begin{document}


\chapter{Books}
\section{Fiction}
\subsection{Dystopy}

\subsubsection*{George Orwell}

\mybook{Animal Farm}\label{AnimalFarm}

Animal Farm is an allegorical and dystopian novella by George Orwell, first [...]

\mybook{1984}

Nineteen Eighty-Four, often published as 1984, is a dystopian novel [...]

\subsubsection*{Aldous Huxley}

\mybook{Brave New World}

Brave New World is a novel written in 1931 by [...]

\section{Interpretation}

I'd like to Reference Animal Farm (\ref{AnimalFarm}) as B 1-1 [...]

In \cref{AnimalFarm} we saw that Orwell...

\end{document}
```

[image]

In principle, this would also avoid `\getcurrentref` command.

Comment: Yes, by setting `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}` and removing `\renewcommand*{\paragraphformat}{}` I could just use `\paragraph` instead of `mybook`. Great!

Comment: @thewaywewalk: I already wondered about this strange stuff ...

Comment: Well that was required for the macro to work as intended ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sonmething like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\newcounter{book}
\newcounter{subbook}[book]

\def\bookagraph#1{\stepcounter{book}\stepcounter{subbook} \paragraph{B \arabic{book} -\arabic{subbook} #1}\expandafter\label{bookagraph_\arabic{book}\arabic{subbook}}}

\begin{document}

\arabic{book}

\bookagraph{Heute}

As seen in \nameref{bookagraph_11}

\end{document}
```

For further wishes, please ask.

Comment: I can't get work for my example, the counter is not reset for example.

Comment: @thewaywewalk You see `\newcounter{subbook}[book]`? The second argument [ ] defines, when the counter subbook is reset (if book changes). Maybe you try ChristianHupfers code. He does better code than me.